# \mathaccent for accents in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I have got a new problem. Namely, I just can't get rid of the error message " Use \mathaccent for accents in math mode". I first thought that it is because of the ö, but the error remains even if I take away the ö.

```
\begin{equation} 
\underbrace{SiO_2}_{\substack{Siliciumdioxid\\der~Gesteins-\\körnung}} 
\to \underbrace{H_2SiO_4^{2-}}_{\substack{Kieselsäure\\-Ionen}}
 \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
```

Thanks a lot for every support!

Comment: don't who only snippets, always extend them to a small but complete example. Use `\textrm{körnung}` around all your text parts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Surely you got two errors, one for the ö and one for the ä. You should wrap text that is not math in `\text{}` or some similar macro.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and now it says "Misplaced \cr."

Comment: Put the ``\\`` outside the `\text`...

Comment: Thanks until here already! Now in another line Latex says "Missing { inserted." I cant´t see that one is missing so maybe Latex already added it. But why does it still show the error? I can ask this in a new question as an complete example but mybe you see the mistake at first view: \underbrace{Na_2SiO_3}_{\substack{\textrm{Alkali-}\\\textrm{Silikat-Gel}}}

Answer (score 3):

As @JesperHabicht has already suggested in a comment, use `\text` (or `\textup`) to encase the text snippets in the argument of `\substack`. Furthermore, I'd suggest using `\tiny` (instead of the default `\scriptsize`) to typeset the text snippets, to assure that they don't come to dominate visually the chemical formulas.

Finally, do yourself a favor and use a package such as [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) and its macro `\ce` to typeset chemical formulas. That'll also help with expressions such as

```
\underbrace{\ce{Na2SiO3}}_{\substack{%
    \textup{Alkali-} \\ \textup{Silikat-Gel}}}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \underbrace, \substack, and \text macros
\newcommand\ttext[1]{\textup{\tiny #1}}
\usepackage{mhchem} % for \ce macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
\underbrace{\ce{SiO2}}_{\substack{%
  \ttext{Siliciumdioxid} \\ \ttext{der Gesteins-} \\ \ttext{körnung}}} 
\longrightarrow
\underbrace{\ce{H2SiO4^{2-}}}_{\substack{%
  \ttext{Kieselsäure-} \\ \ttext{Ionen}}}
\end{equation}

\[
\underbrace{\ce{Na2SiO3}}_{\substack{%
        \textup{\tiny Alkali-} \\ \textup{\tiny Silikat-Gel}}}
\]
\end{document}
```